# Windows 7 Error Loading Operating System

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, truecrypt

I have a Windows 7 SP1 machine with

- C: 120GB SSD
- D: 2TB HD
- E: 500GB HD

All disks are truecrypt encrypted with D and E being system favorite volumes. Today I booted the machine and I got the dreaded Operating System not found error. I booted into the Truecrypt Rescue CD and tried to restore the boot loader. It failed. I then decided to decrypt the system drive, which succeeded after about an hour.

I then booted the machine and I get Error Loading Operating System.

So, I boot from the Windows 7 DVD and select Repair and go to the command prompt and do the following:

```
X:\Sources>diskpart

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status       Size     Free     
  --------- -----------  -------- -------
  Disk 0    Online       111 GB   0 B
  Disk 1    Online       1863 GB  1863 GB
  Disk 2    Online       465 GB   0 B

DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type          Size     Offset
  -------------  ------------- -------- -------
* Partition 1    Primary       111 GB   0 B

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs    Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------- ---- ------------ ----- ----------- -------- ---------- -------
  Volume 0     E   GRMCULXFRER  UDF   DVD-ROM     3075 MB  Healthy
  Volume 1     C                RAW   Partition   111 GB   Healthy
  Volume 2     D                RAW   Partition   465 GB   Healthy

DISKPART>
```

**EDIT:**

I also tried Startup Repair from the System Recovery Options dialog and it found a corrupt partition table on Disk 0, but says it repaired it. When I reboot, the machine doesn't find the operating system and Startup Repair finds the partition table to be corrupt again on the next boot. Here's a screenshot

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDqle.jpg)[image]

I'm not sure how to recover the boot sector of my SSD. Any ideas?

Comment: It's seems like Your System MBR damaged you try Could repair the MBR it may be solve your problem, or run time select your hard-drive you want to boot from or you could repair your operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this and ended up reinstalling Windows.